# Seeing if one value exists in another column by ID

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Dataframe is as follows:

```
Target  Source      Source_Match
A       source1     source2
A       source2     source4
A       source3     source1
B       source1     source2
B       source3     source4
B       source4     source5
C       source5     source2
C       source6     source3
C       source7     source4
```

I want to see if the values in "Source_Match" exist in each "Target's" "Source" list.

Final result should look like this:

```
Target  Source       Source_Match   Found In Target?
A       source1      source2        Yes
A       source2      source4        No
A       source3      source1        Yes
B       source1      source2        No
B       source3      source4        Yes
B       source4      source5        No
C       source5      source2        No
C       source6      source3        No
C       source7      source4        No
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I don't see a pattern, could you explain further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dplyrish way is:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(Target) %>% mutate(found = Source_Match %in% Source)
```

---

The analogous data.table code is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, found := Source_Match %in% Source, by=Target]
```

If the "source" columns are of character type, `%chin%` can be used in place of `%in%`. It is a faster version specialized to this case available in the data.table package. (Thanks, @akrun.)

And another idea, from @eddi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621735/seeing-if-one-value-exists-in-another-column-by-id/37621804#comment62726654_37621804):

> a faster? alternative:
>
> ```
> DF[, found := 'No'][DF, on = .(Target, Source_Match = Source), found := 'Yes']
> ```

Comment: I can't install the package: data.frame

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. Should've written dplyr not data.frame there. Fixed

Comment: Ok thanks! So the first one didn't work for me but the second part did. Thanks!

Comment: a faster? alternative: `DF[, found := 'No'][DF, on = .(Target, Source_Match = Source), found := 'Yes']`

Answer (score 0):

Using the base package. I'm sure there are much more efficient ways to do it using the base package.

```
df1 <- df[, c(1,2)]
df2 <- df[, c(1,3)]
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)
df$found <- duplicated(rbind(df1,df2))[(nrow(df)+1):(nrow(df)*2)]
```

Output:

```
 Target  Source Source_Match found
1      A source1      source2  TRUE
2      A source2      source4 FALSE
3      A source3      source1  TRUE
4      B source1      source2 FALSE
5      B source3      source4  TRUE
6      B source4      source5 FALSE
7      C source5      source2 FALSE
8      C source6      source3 FALSE
9      C source7      source4 FALSE
```